# How do I get the intersection of columns in the same table given certain criteria?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have the following table:

```
E1
+-------+------------+-----------+---------+
|  ID   | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | SOME_ID |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------+
| GUID1 | John       | Smith     | O1      |
| GUID2 | John       | Smith     | O2      |
| GUID3 | Andrew     | Smith     | O3      |
| GUID4 | Sam        | Jackson   | O1      |
| GUID5 | John       | Jones     | O2      |
| GUID6 | Sam        | Jackson   | O2      |
+-------+------------+-----------+---------+
```

If given a list of "SOME_ID" values, I need to get the intersecting values for "FIRST_NAME" and "LAST_NAME".

So for example, if "SOME_ID" is 01 and 02. Then the result will be the following:

```
Result
+------------+-----------+
| FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME |
+------------+-----------+
| John       | Smith     |
| Sam        | Jackson   |
+------------+-----------+
```

This is due to the fact that both 01 and 02 correspond to rows which have a "FIRST_NAME" of John and "LAST_NAME" of Smith. The same logic applies for the Sam Jackson row.

So far, I have come up with the following query:

```
(select first_name, last_name
from E1
where some_id = '01')
intersect
(select first_name, last_name
from E1
where some_id = '02');
```

This does give me the result of exactly what I want, however, it seems that there'll be a new query for each new value of "SOME_ID". This seems quite inefficient?

Is there a better way to do this? Perhaps through joins?

The other idea I had was to just get a union of all the values, and programmatically get the intersection in memory. I could be wrong, but this seems that this method would be faster if there is no better way than the way I had mentioned above.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `group by` and `having`.

```
select first_name, last_name
from E1
where some_id in ('01','02')
group by first_name, last_name
having count(distinct some_id) = 2
```

Comment: WHERE clause should come before the GROUP BY clause. I will edit to correct it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that uses `group by` rather than `join`:

```
select first_name, last_name
from e1
where some_id in ('01', '02')
group by first_name, last_name
having count(distinct some_id) = 2;
```

The performance should be pretty stable  as you add more ids (change the "2" to the number of ids).

Comment: I noticed that you used "having" instead of the "where" clause (comparing it to the other answer). Is there a reason? Does it make a difference in this scenario?

Comment: The first HAVING should be WHERE instead. I will edit to correct it.